# Jekyll blog on github page not show my new post but It works on localhost:4000

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Sorry, I am new to jekyll.
Recently I make a blog by github-page+ jekyll and use somebody`s template

this one
https://github.com/Huxpro/huxpro.github.io

and modify code to use on my blog

but the problem is that :
Jekyll blog on github page not show my new post but It works on localhost:4000
and I search the answer for some  page
but I still could not find the answer....

this is my github

https://github.com/intheblackworld/intheblackworld.github.io

Comment: I search some page like  
 
http://talk.olab.io/t/jekyll-posts-md-not-showing-up-as-html-when-pushed-to-github/321  

still not found the answer  
  
this is the blog website
http://intheblackworld.github.io/

Comment: I hit this problem every now and again, make sure the name of the post is in the correct format: yyyy-mm-dd-name.md
The last time I hit the problem, another push to GitHub solved it, so you could try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. If you mean "GitHub not rendering all new posts after a specific post":

Solution is **check your date format**.

Check your [YAML header](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/)

You may quote your YAML header:

```
----
date: "2016-03-16"
----
```

### 2. If you mean "GitHub not rendering my very newest post"

Solution is **Make another commit and push to GitHub**

I encounter this problem too.

Have no idea why but this may help.